org-mode collapse babel when cursor in babel code block
I usually edit python code in org-babel block, then press C-c C-c to run the code block. then I check the results at the RESULTS section.
But if the code lines larger than the screen height, then I need scroll down to see the results.
Is it possible to just hit TAB in the middle of org-babel to collapse the code then results section show more quick (no need scroll down too much)
I know hit TAB at the #+begin_src or #+end_src will collapse it, but move cursor to there waste time.

You can move the cursor to the beginning of a source block with C-c C-v C-u (bound to org-babel-goto-src-block-head): it really doesn't take that much time.
You can even set the mark before you do that, so you can go back to the same place easily:

set the mark (C-<space>)
go to the head of the block (C-c C-v C-u)
fold it (TAB)
look around in the results
go back to the mark and continue editing (C-x C-x)

Once you get the sequence into your finger memory, it's almost instant.
I would not recommend modifying the behavior of TAB inside a code block. The code does a carefully balanced dance to make sure that TAB inside the code block emulates the global behavior of TAB (i.e. indent-for-tab-command), but it looks fragile to me, so if you change it, I would not be surprised if the whole house came down. If you are still determined to do it, the function that implements the behavior is org-fold--hide-wrapper-toggle in org-fold.el (since Org version 9.5.5 - I don't know how older versions did it). Tread carefully...

Awesome, any shortcut to jump to end of the block?

I didn't see a function to do that, but it should be easy enough to cobble one up.
